# Multiple ckpt, meta into single .pb file?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, the training produced the following files:

```
checkpoint
model.ckpt-10000.meta
model.ckpt-10000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-10000.index

model.ckpt-11000.meta
model.ckpt-11000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-11000.index

model.ckpt-12000.meta
model.ckpt-12000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-12000.index

model.ckpt-8000.meta
model.ckpt-8000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-8000.index

model.ckpt-9000.meta
model.ckpt-9000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-9000.index
```

I am interested in creating a .pb file from the output generated training; however, from the examples I have seen, it requires one set of intermediate output files. How do I merge all the output set files into a single .pb?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do does not make sense (at least to me). I recommend you to read about these checkpoint files [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints) at first.

In short, `checkpoint` file just tells you what is the latest model. The `.meta` file stores info about your graph structure, `.data` stores values for variables and `.index` stores key/value pairs which have info where the values for each parameter can be found in .data files.

All your files look like `model.ckpt-xxxx`. This `xxxx` is the step number. So you have snapshots of training at different steps. And this is why it does not make sense to combine the value of the variable at step 9000 with the value at step 11000. Also `.meta` files are probably all the same.